# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()

Tags: android

I have recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio and in doing so I have picked up the below error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItemImpl.java:740)
        at biz.nickbullcomputing.bevnav.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:699)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2851)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:277)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:84)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:273)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1111)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1396)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:126)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
```

This error appears to becoming from the following code snippet of my main activity

```
 searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

     searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener()
     {
         @Override
         public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
             townList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             return true;       // Return true to collapse action view
         }
         @Override
         public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
             townList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             return true;      // Return true to expand action view
         }
     });
```

The search's xml code:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

My build.gradle file's dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

}

Now keep in mind before the migration this was working perfectly and now it's not. I'm not entirely sure how this has happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use `MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener` instead of `MenuItemImpl.OnActionExpandListener`

Comment: I have tried this but get an error of `Method Call Expected` am I missing an import somewhere?

Comment: Oh wiat i've got it thanks @ρяσѕρєя K that did the trick

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The fix thanks to ρяσѕρєя K's comment. Much appreciated mate, thank you!!

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // Return true to allow the action view to expand
                    townList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // When the action view is collapsed, reset the query
                    townList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    // Return true to allow the action view to collapse
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I am using same exact class and method, but still it's not working! :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your compile dependency because it is deprecated in [setOnActionExpandListener 26.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem,%20android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener)) Check your app/build.gradle. I had faced the same issue and below config help me out. Hope this will work for you.

Here is my build.gradle config.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
targetSdkVersion 25

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // Return true to allow the action view to expand
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // When the action view is collapsed, reset the query
                        // Return true to allow the action view to collapse
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```